# RedLevel1 and Cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, shared-libraries

I'm aware that this seems to be quite a common error, but I have attempted multiple solutions and nothing so far. To be fair, I'm not particularly knowledgeable about Linux, so this might be more of a case of personal shortcomings. Anyway, on to the actual problem.

I'm trying to run a program named `RedLevel1` located in the folder `~/Level1`. Attempting to execute it results in the following output:

```
$ ~/Level1/.libs/RedLevel1: error while loading shared libraries: liblevelone.so.0: cannot open shared 
object file: No such file or directory
```

I then go to the directory specified by the error to search for the missing library.

```
$~/Level1/.libs/ ls
ADCBoard.o   EvRaw0.o               liblevelone.rootmap    RedLevel1
ADCEvent.o   EvRec0.o               liblevelone.so         RootIO.o
ADCFile.o    liblevelone.a          liblevelone.so.0       RunHeader.o
Analyzer.o   liblevelone.la         liblevelone.so.0.0.0   VDecoder.o
DBService.o  liblevelone.lai        liblevelone.so.0.0.0T  viewer
Decoder.o    liblevelone_rdict.o    MCDecoder.o            viewer_online
EvHeader.o   liblevelone_rdict.pcm  RDconfig.o
```

So the desired library `liblevelone.so.0` is there, at least to the best of my understanding. I do not know why it can't be found. I have attempted to run `sudo ldconfig` and added the path containing the library to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to no avail. I understand that this might seem a simple fix, but I'm having quite a hard time. Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

EDIT: Should have added this originally, but I'm running Ubuntu 18.04. Also, I am not the one who built and configured the program in question. I'm part of a research group and the code is used to simulated some physics data. Another member was the one who configured it for me, but he's currently on vacation and inaccessible.

Comment: What linux are you running?

Comment: You can see where it expects to find the library by running `ldd Redlevel1`

Comment: @stark running the command returns `liblevelone.so.0 (0x00007f43af50f000)
`  and a number with other libraries, though with the directories indicated.

Comment: Check in your Bash history: `history | grep configure`.

Comment: Not sure what you are saying.  ldd lists the directory path for all libraries.  If there is no '/' before the library, then it expects it to be in your current working directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This really shows how much of a rookie I am, but the problem seemed to have resolved after running `make clean` and running `make` a second time.